# Vagrant can t require log4r

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, vagrant

I m trying to follow [chef quickstart tutorial](https://learnchef.opscode.com/quickstart/converge/), I m doing it on a Ubuntu 12.04 VM.

I ve created the git, cookbook... And I m at the point I m supposed to start vagrant for attaching the node. But even while freshly installed vagrant, I get this error:

```
~/chef-repo$ vagrant up --no-color
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- log4r (LoadError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:2:in '<main>'
```

I tried to apt-get remove vagrant, it show that a package log4r will become useless.

Even after reinstallation it give me the error.

I don t know what I made wrong, and have no idea on how to solve this.

EDIT: If I try with advanced setup, I get stuck at chef installation via gem:

```
~$ gem install chef
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Command::InstallCommand
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think this is a problem with vagrant, I think something went wrong during chef installation.

Comment: I m trying to uninstall everything and try again from 0

Comment: Retried from clean image, no error during installation process, all command copy/pasted from tutorial, and still this error.

Comment: Have you used the quick or the advanced option in the "workstation setup" page?

Comment: Quick setup the two time, should I try the advanced?

Comment: you culd try the advanced... but before just try to install she log4r gem. As root try `gem install log4r`

Comment: Tried to install with gem, didn t work.
I m trying with advanced setup.

Comment: How did you install Vagrant? Log4r is the logging library used by Vagrant. If it's not present, something wonky happened with your vagrant install, probably when you did `apt-get remove vagrant`,

Comment: Well, `sudo apt-get install vagrant`, no error message, tried installing virtualbox by vagrant, before or after it, but got the error at `vagrant up`in all cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Vagrant seems to use Chef's embedded ruby. I guess you installed Vagrant from Ubuntu's repository?

Download the official Debian/Ubuntu package from [the downloads page](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads), and install it from command line using:

```
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_*.deb
```

(Synaptic sometimes seems to try to pull down things from distro's repos when just double-clicking a .deb)

Comment: It wasn t the exact answer, but helped me find the answer: when doing apt-get, I was installing 32bit version, when downloading and dpkg the 64bit, it worked.